# Render problem in Preview of Navigation Drawer in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, render, preview

I am having a problem with Preview of generated Navigation Drawer layout in Android Studio 3.4.

I've tried to change layout Theme or change API version for Preview but none of these seem to help. The Render problem's error trace looks like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@26b35b5d
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor306.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:674)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:637)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1069)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1088)
at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
at android.animation.ValueAnimator.startWithoutPulsing(ValueAnimator.java:1081)
at android.animation.AnimatorSet.handleAnimationEvents(AnimatorSet.java:1142)
at android.animation.AnimatorSet.startAnimation(AnimatorSet.java:1227)
at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:729)
at android.animation.AnimatorSet.start(AnimatorSet.java:684)
at android.animation.StateListAnimator.start(StateListAnimator.java:188)
at android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:181)
at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:21105)
at android.widget.ImageView.drawableStateChanged(ImageView.java:1294)
at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.drawableStateChanged(FloatingActionButton.java:804)
at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:21160)
at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18379)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:335)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:391)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:195)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:540)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:666)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDIT** 
When I rebuild the Project or Invalidate Cashes and restart, the Preview appears to work, bud when I close it and reopen it, the Render error appears again.

**Activity_main.xml:**

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does the layout work if you build and run it on a device? If no, you've got some other error to resolve. If yes, add the layout. If you're using a custom view, that might trigger it. If you aren't, that sounds like a bug in either the editor or the view

Comment: Yes, I am testing the app on my phone and the layout works good. I added the layout to the question. Could you please check it? Maybe you'll find something. Thank you

Comment: I just realized this problem is from FloatingActionButton. Remove it and the preview works.

Comment: @MbuodileObiosio Thank you for your help, this really worked for me. I wonder if there's a way to fix this if I would like to use the FloatingActionButton?

Comment: What I had to do was use an ImageView, set all constraints like I need then change to FAB and include everything as relates to FAB. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the answer to this question so anybody having the same issue can relate to this in the future.
As Mbuodile Obiosio mentioned in a comment, a solution or workaround to solve this problem is to **remove the FloatingActionButton** from the layout.

Comment: I had the same problem but with many different views (AppBarLayout, AppCompatImageView, custom views, and more...) and the Design View broke entirely when I made a change either by xml or by design view. My solution was to Invalidate Caches and Restart every it brokes...

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Solved it after removing this line:

```
tools:openDrawer="start"
```